# PHP Loose Comparisons

Tags: php

Why doesn't this evaluate to true

```
php > var_dump('1e123' == '1');
bool(false)
```

This obviously does, but I don't understand why using 1 wouldn't.

```
php > var_dump('0e123' == '0');
bool(true)
```

Comment: If you ever actually have to rely on behaviour like this you are in a _lot_ of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This numbers (with `e`) are written as strings, but in reality they are treated by PHP as floats when doing loose comparison. They are written using [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation), which simply means that the part after `e` is the exponent in `N x M^E`. `0` multiplied by anything is `0`. `0 x 10^123` is still `0`. However, `1 x 10^123` is a very large number, much bigger than `1`.

PHP casts the first string to a double(float) and the other operand to an int. Comparing a float with int results in float comparison. The same could be written as follows:

```
var_dump(1e123 == 1);
var_dump(0e123 == 0);
```

If you tried to compare it using strict comparison it would fail, because strict comparison checks not only value, but also type. Comparing float with int, even if mathematically having the same value, would result in false. Comparing two strings with different textual value, would also lead to false result.

However, due to the fact that exponential numbers in PHP are of type float, you can lose precision with such huge numbers. e.g.

```
var_dump('1.0000000000000000001e123' == '1e123'); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I reworded my answer to be more in line with what you were asking. I hope it is clearer what is going on.